# Empty space in UISplitViewController embedded in a UITabViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller, uicontainerview

I have this view hierarchy on my storyboard:

`UITabBarController` -> `UIView` + `ContainerController` -> `SplitViewController` => [MASTER: (`UINavigationController` -> `UITableviewController` -> `UITableViewController`), DETAIL: (`UINavigationController` -> `UIView`)]

Here a screenshot of the storyboard:

[image]

As a result my detail view controller have a sort of **offset** from the bottom screen as shown in the red circle in the next screen:

[image]

I think it is a consequence of having a split view controller in a container controller that its **embedded** in a tab controller. It's like the detail view inherits the space of the tab bar of the root tab bar controller. I have tried to set all the options like **UnderBottombar** or "Under opaque bar" but nothing. I have removed any sort of custom code in my classes but there is always the same problem.
How can i fix this issue?

ps: Sorry for bad english :)

Comment: Do you need the container?

Comment: Yes i do because i'm implementing iAd. I'm using the sample code of apple for doing it.

Comment: have you solved this, @Andorath? I am having the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

This can be solved by checking `Under Opaque Bars` from `attribute inspector` of your `SplitViewController`. refer below screenshot,

[image]

Comment: I checked the "Under Opaque Bars" in the embedded view controller and worked!

Comment: I had like 3 days looking for this! Many thanks both!